# 404 Error from old hosting site keeps coming up

Tags: web-hosting, 404, github

I previously hosted my website on a free hosting website (http://www.000webhost.com) but today moved it to GitHub for use with their user-page service. After moments, my page was loading from my GitHub repo and so I deleted my website account on the free hosting website. After doing that, whenever I typed in my website's url (www.haigmac.com), it would redirect to the free hosting 404 error page. Even if I direct the browser to my GitHub URL (mghaight.github.io), it goes to the 404 page.

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my CNAME or A host DNS settings. I'm including an image of my settings here:
[image]

Any help getting my domain pointing at my GitHub page is very appreciated.

I should note that I did clear my cache/history and have tried this on multiple browsers. Could this just be an issue of time?

Comment: It was just a time issue! All figured out...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely caused by your TTL values or DNS not propagating.

> Time to live is what dictates how long it will be until your computer
>   refreshes its DNS related information. For example, the IP address
>   your domain name points to or where your MX records are directing
>   email.
>
> This time is defined in seconds and the default setting can be found
>   in the zone file (available in the AccountCenter under Edit Zone
>   File). The reason this is useful is that if you will be moving hosts,
>   or if you have any sort of DNS information that you need to change, it
>   will take affect in a shorter time interval.
>
> Generally, DNS propagation takes 24 to 48 hours to complete whenever
>   any changes are made to the Zone File. Lowering the TTL prior to
>   making the change will reduce the time for propagation.

Source - https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644120/understanding-ttl-%28time-to-live%29